# Insertar datos usando PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola es que estoy ejecutando los siguientes códigos de PHP-mySql pero no me uno de ellos no me funciona, y tengo la mas mínima idea de porque, a ver si alguno de ustedes sabe como ayudarme y gracias de antemano

Upload.php, este actualiza perfectamente.

```
<?php
include_once "con.php";
switch ($_GET['tipo']) {
    case 1:
    //Modificar el nombre //error
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $id=$_GET['code'];
            $nombre = $_POST['name'];
            $sentencia = $con->prepare("UPDATE birthdays SET name = ? WHERE id = ?;");
            $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$nombre, $id]);
            header('Location: ../admin');


        } 
        else {
            die("No se a recibido nada");
        }   
    break;
    case 2:
    //Modificar el apellido
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $id=$_GET['code'];
            $apellido = $_POST['surname'];
            $sentencia = $con->prepare("UPDATE birthdays SET surname = ? WHERE id = ?;");
            $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$apellido, $id]);
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.location.replace("../admin");
            </script>
            <?php
        } 
        else {
            die("No se a recibido nada");
        }   
    break;
    case 3:
    //Modificar el cargo
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $id=$_GET['code'];
            $job = $_POST['work'];
            $sentencia = $con->prepare("UPDATE birthdays SET job = ? WHERE id = ?;");
            $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$job, $id]);
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.location.replace("../admin");
            </script>
            <?php
        } 
        else {
            die("No se a recibido nada");
        }   
    break;
    case 4:
    //Modificar la fecha de nacimiento
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $id=$_GET['code'];
            $fecha = explode("/", $_POST['birthday']);
            $day = $fecha[0];
            $month = $fecha[1];
            $year = $fecha[2];
            $sentencia = $con->prepare("UPDATE birthdays SET day = ?, month = ?, year = ? WHERE id = ?;");
            $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$day, $month, $year, $id]);
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.location.replace("../admin");
            </script>
            <?php
        } 
        else {
            die("No se a recibido nada");
        }   
    break;
    case 5:
    //Modificar la fecha en la que empezo a trabjar
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $id=$_GET['code'];
            $inicio = $_POST['contratation'];
            $sentencia = $con->prepare("UPDATE birthdays SET start = ? WHERE id = ?;");
            $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$inicio, $id]);
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.location.replace("../admin");
            </script>
            <?php
        } 
        else {
            die("No se a recibido nada");
        }   
    break;
    case 6:
    //Modificar la imagen
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $id=$_GET['code'];
            if (!file_exists('../images/'.$id)) {
                $oldmask = umask(0);
                mkdir('../images/'.$id, 0777);
                umask($oldmask);
            }
            if($fila['image']!=NULL) {
                unlink('../images/'.$id."/".$id.'.png');
            }
            $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            $storeFolder = '../images/'.$id;
            if (!empty($_FILES)) {

                $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];             
                $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
                $targetFile =  $targetPath.$id. ".png";
                move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); 
                $sentencia = $con->prepare("UPDATE birthdays SET image = ? WHERE id = ?;");
                $resultado = $sentencia->execute([$id.'.png', $id]);
            }
            else {
                die("No se a subido nada");
            }

        }
        else {
                die("No se a recibido nada");
        }
    break;
}

?>
```

Save.php este debería crear un nuevo registro pero nunca lo hace, siempre se va por el else, y cuando voy a mirar en la Base de datos no ha insertado nada.

```
<?php
include_once "con.php";
$nombre = 'Seadog';
$apellido = 'Gato';
$job = 'Dañar';
$fecha = explode("/", $_POST['birthday']);
$day = '24';
$month = '09';
$year = '1992';
$inicio = '10/05/2000';
$sentencia = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `birthdays` (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `year`, `month`, `day`, `job`, `start`, `image`, `content`)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
$resultado = $sentencia->execute([NULL, $nombre, $apellidos, $year, $month, $day, $job, $inicio, NULL, NULL]); 

//header('Location: ../admin');
if($resultado === TRUE) echo "Insertado correctamente";
else echo "Algo salió mal. Por favor verifica que la tabla exista";
?>
```

y le hice una prueba con un `try..catch` y me saco el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y el código por el que me saco el error es este: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la BD
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si usas pdo los marcadores deben ser así :variable y no así ?, pues este último es para mysqli

Comment: @shadow aaa yo no sabia, sino que me base de este link `https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/02/12/mysql-php-pdo-crud/` entonces solo modifique, entonces ese sería el error?

Comment: No lo sé aún no reviso a detalle espera

Comment: el id de tu tablas es primary key? por que veo que lo declaras en las columnas y luego en los values asignas un NULL, dime por que haces eso?

Comment: @shadow lo hacia porque al inicio no tenia el Null pero empece a descartar errores así que hice un Insert en phpmyadmin y lo copie y ese salía de esa manera.

Answer (score 0):

En PDO, antes de ejecutar tu query con la función

```
execute();
```

tienes que remplazar los caracteres "?" con las variables que vas a insertar,
debería ser algo así.

```
$sentencia = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `birthdays` (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `year`, `month`, `day`, `job`, `start`, `image`, `content`)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");

$sentecia->bindParam(1, $nombre);
$sentecia->bindParam(2, $apellido);
$sentecia->bindParam(3, $year);
...

$resultado = $sentencia->execute();
if($resultado) echo "Insertado correctamente";
else echo "Algo salió mal. Por favor verifica que la tabla exista";
```

Comment: Ahí en el `execute([...])` estaban las variables correspondientes, pero ya encontré el error, era una bobada realmente 
yo tenia esto: `$apellido = 'Gato';` 
y ejecutaba esto: `$resultado = $sentencia->execute([NULL, $nombre, $apellidos, $year, $month, $day, $job, $inicio, NULL, NULL]);` 

Como puede ver obtenía el valor con `$apellido` y lo intentaba guardar con `$apellidos`, tenia una `s` de mas lo cual la hacia una variable nueva sin definir